# Typescript and resolving promises without the use <any>

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, bluebird

How can I make the *resolve(<any>existingVote)* to compile without the <any >. If I remove the <any> I get **Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Thenable <Object>** in the compiler error window. It seems I may not understand yet how to create a Thennable <Object> for the resolve return.

```
    getExistingVote(): Promise<Parse.Object> {

        return new Promise<Parse.Object>((resolve, reject) => {

            var query = this.getQuery();
            query.first().then(
                (existingVote) => {
                    resolve(<any>existingVote);
                }, (existingVoteError) => {
                    reject(existingVoteError);
                });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dependent on the *inferred* type of `existingVote`. It should be of type : `Parse.Object` If it isn't, then you need to use the type assertion.

**UPDATE**
Based on 
[image]

The definition for `resolve` you have is wrong as it is only taking `Thenable<Object>`. It should really be `Object | Thenable<Object>` similar to https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/lib/typings/atompromise.d.ts#L82

Comment: Hi Basarat, this is what I thought also. Please have a look at the attached link. i.imgur.com/b73jXXq.png

Comment: hover over `existingVote` to see its inferred type https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#type-information-on-hover

Comment: I had posed a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/b73jXXq.png) there, I am using VS2013 which shows the type as being correct.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Perhaps it is because my parse object is not wrapped in Promise.Thenable? http://i.imgur.com/P4fZZF7.png

Comment: Thanks it appears that my def file SHOULD support this: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts#L24

In order to support this I have changed the order of constructors and it works now. The Pipe | does not seem to work, perhaps a newer version of Typescript.

Comment: Yes `|` came with TypeScript 1.4